# Adjust a "for" loops duration

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, loops, for-loop

I'm currently working on an app that will show a label that will start at zero, and count up to a number I specify. I wanted to do this using a simple loop like this one.

```
  for (counterInt = 0; counterInt < 10; counterInt++) 
    {
        NSLog(@"%i",counterInt); 
    }
```

The problem is, that this loop executes in less time than it takes for the view to appear on screen. My console logs 1-9 before the view finally loads with the label with showing 9. I've been researching for several hours trying to find a way to specify a duration for the loop and I can't seem to find any thing on this.

So my overall question is, is it possible to specify how long the loop should take to execute? If so, if anyone can point me in the right direction here it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also, in addition to bellow answers, you may want to put your code in the **-(void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated**  method. This one is called AFTER your view appears on screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if you slowed down the loop, it still wouldn't work. UI elements are only updated at the end of the run loop. You need to set up a [timer](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) and update the label in the method fired by the timer.

Answer (score 4):

You're using the wrong approach.  Try an NSTimer.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(incrementLabel:)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES];
```

Then create a method called incrementLabel and have it increment an instance variable and update the label accordingly.

Comment: This wouldn't perform a countdown unless you set the timer off again in incrementLabel, as you're not repeating. But well done for actually putting some code in. Not sure why my answer got that many upvotes, but you get my +1!

Answer (score 1):

You can sleep a thread:

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
```

However, jrturton and james supply the correct approach. I would place James' code in the viewDidAppear method so your label starts where you want it and the counter begins when the view appears.